Connection to postgres sometimes works but mostly fails
I'm trying to connect to my database from the office where I work. The database is hosted in AWS and I'm using Datagrip. I have a whitelist.tf file included that has the office network added.
When testing the connection I mostly get the following message:
[08001] Connection to "myproject".amazonaws.com:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
But only once in a while I'm actually able to make a successful connection without changing any settings.
I then get:
DBMS: PostgreSQL (ver. 14.10)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=exact
Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (ver. 42.6.0, JDBC4.2)
Ping: 47 ms
SSL: yes
This problem happens to anyone that is trying to make the connection from the office network/vpn. So it will not be related to my personal computer (I think). I've also verified the firewall rules for the network and even added a specific allow rule for the correct ip and port.
The problem does not persist when using any other network when working from home.
I don't know if it's related, but we also host nuget and npm packages in AWS. When restoring or npm installing from the office network, it takes really long. This is also not the case when working from home.
In any other case the network works perfectly fine.
I have no clue where I can look next. Are there settings in AWS that I can verify? Is there something in my database configuration that I can check? Any other options?

Added the IP of the office in the whitelist.tf file
Verified database credentials (sometimes the connection is successful)
Verified firewall rules
Verified if the problem only happens on my machine
Verified that the problem does not happen at home


Are you sure that PosgreSQL is actually running and listening on port 5432 when you're seeing connection refused? Can you SSH onto the instance and connect using psql? Connection refused (packet rejected) suggests that no server process is listening as opposed to connection timeout (packet dropped) which suggests a firewall or AWS security group mis-configuration.

Yes, because sometimes I can actually make a succesfull connection and browse the database. This seems totally random

Right, but that's only sometimes. I'm asking in the scenario when you cannot connect. At that moment in time, is the PostgreSQL server up and does netstat or other show it actively listening on port 5432? Also, what do the PG logs say about connection counts, connection failures?

whitelist.tf?  Team Fortress?  Please reference or add a tag for whatever this thing is.
